# Compare two table and adding row based on condition

Tags: r, join, merge

I would like to compare ***dt1*** to ***dt2*** such that if ***dt1*** A column value exist when it compare to ***dt2*** A column value it would not add a row or change the value in that row. So when the value are different like shown in the example where ***dt2*** has "4" & "5" in A column it will add "4" & "5" to ***dt1*** table but it would not replace it's "1", "2" or "3" value in ***dt1*** A column since it existed already.

Edit: I would like to use A column in a form of a primary key to check something along the line of if "1" exist in A column in both both table then nothing changes but if in there is a A column value in ***dt2***(Example:"4") but not in ***dt1***  then i wan that row of data to merge with dt1 table

```
dt1 
A   B   C   
1   4   7   
2   5   8   
3   6   9   

dt2
A   B   C  
1   10  13  
2   12  15  
3   11  14  
4   1   20
5   12  3

dt1
A   B   C   
1   4   7   
2   5   8   
3   6   9    
4   1   20
5   12  3
```

Comment: Relevant post: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind `dt1` with rows from `dt2` that don't have `A` values in `dt1` with just one conditional statement

```
rbind(dt1, dt2[!(dt2$A %in% dt1$A),])
#   A  B  C
# 1 1  4  7
# 2 2  5  8
# 3 3  6  9
# 4 4  1 20
# 5 5 12  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `dplyr`, we get the rows that are in 'dt2' that are not in 'dt1' grouped by 'A' with `anti_join` and `rbind` with 'dt1' using `bind_rows`

```
 library(dplyr)
 anti_join(dt2, dt1, by='A') %>% 
                       bind_rows(dt1, .)
```

Or another option would be using `rbindlist` to rbind both the datasets and get the `unique` based on 'A' column.

```
 library(data.table)
 unique(rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2)), by='A')
```

Or as @Arun mentioned in the comments, if we use the devel version of 'data.table' i.e. v1.9.5 (Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)), `on` option can be used to join the two datasets without specifying the keys to get the rows in 'dt2'  that are not in 'dt1' and `rbind` with the 'dt1'

```
  rbind(dt1, dt2[!dt1, on="A"])
```